# Abstract Algebra Group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

Let $G:= \{ e^z \;:\; z\in\mathbb{C}\}$ form a group under multiplication.

Question : G is isomorphic with which group?

Comment: The isomorphism is right there in the question itself. :)

Comment: I'm not getting it...

Comment: As noted down in below answer you should be able to see that any complex number can be written in the form $e^z$ for some complex number $z$...

Answer (score 3):

HINT: For $z = a + bi \in \mathbb{C}$,
$$ e^z = e^a(\cos(b) + i \sin (b)). $$

Comment: then what to do?? @tylerco816

Comment: I claim that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{ 0 \}$.  To set up the isomorphism, you need to be able to write $e^z$ as a complex number, which is where the hint comes into play.

Comment: That is, any sum of two real numbers in the domain corresponds to the product of two positive real numbers in the range. This shows that, algebraically, multiplication of positive real numbers and addition of real numbers _exhibit the same structure_. In other words, they are isomorphic. 

The function f(x) above is the actual isomorphism, which shows the structures are isomorphic.